# What's the use of Displaying ^V or ^C in Terminal?

Tags: terminal

When you try to paste stuff into a terminal with CTRL+V, instead of pasting the stuff you wanted to paste, it just only adds `^V`

Actually i never found out what is actually going to be the use of this functionality. Can someone explain me what people were supposed to do with this?

Comment: Let's say you have a program which reads user input. If the user wants to input ASCII character 22 (in decimal, or 0x16) to the program, he would have to type Ctrl+V twice (once for escaping, once for actually typing 0x16).

Comment: Could you provide me a source for this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the two examples questioned:

- <kbd>control</kbd><kbd>V</kbd> is usually used as the "literal next" character.  For instance, you might use it to enter a <kbd>control</kbd><kbd>S</kbd> character in a text-editor rather than using <kbd>control</kbd><kbd>S</kbd> as the XOFF flow-control character.
- <kbd>control</kbd><kbd>C</kbd> is often used for the keyboard *interrupt* character (sending a `SIGINT` to any program(s) watching the terminal).

You can read about these in

- [`stty`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/stty.1.html) manual page (change and print terminal line settings)
- [Unprintable ASCII characters and TTYs](http://www.in-ulm.de/~mascheck/various/ascii-tty/)  overview by Sven Mascheck
- [SIGTERM with a keyboard shortcut](https://superuser.com/questions/343031/sigterm-with-a-keyboard-shortcut)